# Whats the best way to fetch an object from server and use it in a page loaded in ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I have two JSPs : A and B. A.jsp is a container jsp and on load of A.jsp using jQuery/Javascript I'm loading B.jsp through Ajax.

I need to compare values loaded in B.jsp with a set of variables stored in my database. (they need to be fetched once only because they won't be changing.)

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

in A.jsp, include the variables as session variables.

```
<s:set var="var1" value="Obj1" scope="session"/>
```

in B.jsp i use the variable

```
<s:if test="%{ajaxVal < var1.val1}" />true</s:if>
```

Comment: I don't understand; is this an answer, or something that should have been an edit to your question?

Comment: @DaveNewton - this is the approach i have taken - hence i have put it up as an answer. if you have any better suggestions pls put it up as an answer